# How to know which interface is bound to which kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel-module, network-interface

As the title asks,

```
How to know wihch interface is bound to which kernel module?
```

I suspect the info should be somewhere in /sys directory, but I failed to find one.

Comment: This belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this:

```
# ethtool -i eth0
driver: e1000e
version: 1.5.1-k
firmware-version: 5.6-2
bus-info: 0000:01:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
```

so the driver for eth0 is e1000e.